# How to create dynamic angular JS 4 child components based on a previous server side call

Tags: angularjs, components, parent-child, eventemitter

As soon as my application is launched, I access the IP address of the client and pass it on to the server. Based on the client IP the server will furnish some data.

Using this data I will decide how many child components should be embedded on the page, like using a **ng-for loop**.

My problem is, the server side call takes time to come back. By that time the **ng-for loop** is done with zero records.

How can I wait till the server call is returned and then initiate the **"ng-for loop"** ?

I tried using **"EventEmitter"** from the parent. I will emit an event on the parent component once the parent gets some value from the server. But the child components are not receiving the emitted event. Then I realized that, it's only working when child emits the event, the parent can catch it. Is this right ? Can the parent emit an event and can all the child components listen and catch it ?

Please advise.

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 0):

I think's you need to check if your data is not empty.

Try this:

```
<div *ngIf="myArray" *ngFor="let item of myArray">{{item | json}}</div>
```

When your variable `myArray` will be completed your ngFor working.